# QuickTime Player inside mediaelements.js - strange bug

Tags: macos, firefox, mediaelement.js

developers.

I'm using mediaelements.js plugin for displaying video on a site, I'm developing. So the problem is that when I open the url with Firefox 3.6 on Mac with MACOS, QuickTime player is show inside the mejs player:
http://gyazo.com/70dc452527ac8e219497e7b193d88d17.png?1354549129

If anybody can tell me why is that happening, I'll be very happy.

Thanks in advance,
Le Koki

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt look like the MEJS is even getting fired. did you instantiate MediaElementPlayer?